# Why won't evaluation vmr for Solace send syslog events over tcp?

Tags: solace

I have an evaluation version of Solace in Virtual box.

It is using a bridged network adapter.

I have configured syslog to dispatch events over tcp:

```
Facility: command, system, event
Hosts: 192.168.1.6:5514 transport tcp
```

However the device won't send syslog events to my Kiwi Syslog server on another computer in the local network.

I can see the events being written to the local log file using command:

```
show log command
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syslog over TCP works fine for me for on `soltr-7.1.1.327-vmr-evaluation`.

Can you confirm the following?

1. There's no firewall blocking the TCP connection on the computer with Kiwi Syslog server.
2. The correct syslog port is specified. I believe that Kiwi uses port 1584 as the default tcp syslog port. You can verify this under Inputs -> TCP in Kiwi's setup.

Comment: A good night's sleep and some further firewall debugging revealed issues in configuration in hostname and firewall. Thanks for confirming that the high level procedure for configuration was correct.